# JPQL query performance

Tags: sql, jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, jpql

Two JPQL query defined below , Which one has more effective performance (in time constraint) or they have equal performance-

**ParentEntity <=> ChildEntity** [Many to Many relationship exist]

```
SELECT me from ChildEntity me where me <> All(select me.childEntitiesRef from ParentEntity pe where pe.parentId=:parentId)
```

or

```
SELECT me FROM ChildEntity me, ParentEntity pe WHERE me NOT MEMBER OF pe.childEntitiesRef AND pe.parentId=:parentId
```

---

```
 class ParentEntity{
       @Id
       String parentId; 
       @ManyToMany
       List<ChildEntity> childEntitiesRef;
    }

 class ChildEntity {  
      @Id
      String childId;  
    }
```

Comment: What relationship exists between ChildEntity and ParentEntity, you can put the entity classes with their attributes?

Comment: ManyToMany relationship exists between ChildEntity and ParentEntity .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try them both a see, that is the only real way to know.

Neither is very efficient, as they both use sub-selects, which are normally less efficient than joins.  MEMBER OF will use a sub-select.  The best solution is to figure out how to write the same query using joins, no sub-selects.  But it also depends on how good your database's optimizer is, it may optimize out the sub-select.

Answer (score 0):

not need to use the parent entity in the query, you can use the child entity reference:

```
where me.parentId.parentId (<>=...) param
```

first time you user a entity ORM load in memory data that is why firt time you perceive slow...